# Speed up iterations of piecewise regressions with the segmented function in R

Tags: r, performance, linear-regression, piecewise

I am trying to fit about 300 piecewise regressions with the `segmented` function from the `segmented` package in R. This is taking a lot of time (~4days) because of the `segmented` function. I am already using all the cores of my computer, but I am not a programmer and I guess this code is probably not optimal. Can I improve the code below to make it run faster? How?

Here is a reproducible example. `df` is a simulated data frame that corresponds to one of the 300 datasets that I want to analyze. Each dataset is one day, and during each day I measure the temperature every 5 minutes, `x` is the temperature and `y` the time of the day. The figure below shows what my data look like. The pattern is very specific and repeatable across days and each change in slope corresponds to well understood biological mechanisms. This is why I can guess all the values of psi (for ex. time of sunrise and sunset).

Of course the real data are more variable and I use many iterations (about 200, here I reduced to 10 for the example) to increase my chances of getting a successful fit.

```
library(segmented)
y<-seq(1,288,1)
x<-c(seq(0,-30,-1),seq(-30,-54,-2),seq(-54,30,1),seq(30,10,-1),seq(10,90,1),seq(90,34,-1))
df<-data.frame(x,y)
head(df)

plot(x~y)
t1=31
t2=44
t3=129
t4=150
t5=231

iterations<-10
for (j in 1:iterations) {           
  res <- lm(formula=x~y,data=df)      
  try(result <- segmented(
       res, seg.Z=~y, psi=c(t1,t2,t3,t4,t5),
       control=seg.control(it.max=200, display=F, K=4, h=0.1, n.boot=100, random=T)))          
}

result
```

[image: Temperature ~ time of the day]

Taking the `lm` out of the loop doesn't significantly improve the speed of the loop.

Comment: can you give example of your data? what is t1, ..., t5?

Comment: 300 segmented regressions with 5 breakpoints each? I have serious doubts that this is a sensible approach for whichever statistical problem you are trying to solve. You might be able to speed this up by supplying better starting values if your data really follows a linear relationship with 5 breakpoints. However, that's probably not the case since that is extremely rare in real-world data.

Comment: Instead of `lm` you can use `lm.fit()`, which does give less complete output, but is much faster and you can just extract what you need.

Comment: Three questions: 1. Did you profile your code; is `lm` or `segmented` taking most of the time? 2. Where the parallelism you talk about is done? 3. Can you move `res <- lm(formula=x~y,data=df)` out of the loop?

Comment: I added a repeatable example (one of the 300 days as df). The 5 breakpoints correspond to well understood biological mechanisms, and are quite obvious when looking at the data. A consequence of that is that the starting values are relatively precise and predictable. `segmented` seems to take the most time, I can remove lm from the loop but there is no significant effect on the global time of the loop. I manually divide my dataset and run each part in different sessions of R on different cores (to avoid bugs between parallelization and the segmented function).

Comment: What exactly is the iteration being done here? As far as I can tell you run 10 tries of `segmented` in your for loop, but there's no dependence on previous results in your segmented function. If that is the case then a simple `mclapply` with `library(parallel)` instead of the for loop should speed you up significantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing that should help is to break out of the iterations once the result is found. In most cases it should find something on the first iteration and this will avoid running 200 unnecessary iterations.

```
rm(result)
for (j in 1:iterations) {           
  res <- lm(formula=x~y,data=df)
  try(result <- segmented(
       res, seg.Z=~y, psi=c(t1,t2,t3,t4,t5),
       control=seg.control(it.max=200, display=F, K=4, h=0.1, n.boot=100, random=T)))
  if (exists("result")) break
}
```